# Dotnet high memory usage on Mac os

Tags: c#, .net-core, macos-catalina, asdf-vm

I have installed .Net Core 3.1.300 with asdf-vim and was following [csharp tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/intro-to-csharp/branches-and-loops-local#make-if-and-else-work-together). When i run:

```cs
dotnet new console -n BranchesAndLoops -o .
```

it does use a lot of memory. Is this the norm in C# world? Or have misconfigured something as a dotnet newbie?

[image]

```
❯ dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.1.300
 Commit:    b2475c1295

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  10.15
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.10.15-x64
 Base Path:   /Users/ogirginc/.asdf/installs/dotnet-core/3.1.300/sdk/3.1.300/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.4
  Commit:  0c2e69caa6

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.1.300 [/Users/ogirginc/.asdf/installs/dotnet-core/3.1.300/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.4 [/Users/ogirginc/.asdf/installs/dotnet-core/3.1.300/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.4 [/Users/ogirginc/.asdf/installs/dotnet-core/3.1.300/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Comment: Running that same command on my Windows 10 machine took so little time I couldn't even get to the Task Manager to see how much memory it took... ‍♂️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though, I had installed dotnet with asdf-vm, later I had downloaded both the Visual Studio for Mac and Visual Studio Code (installed additional stuff, which I have no idea what they are) to try them rather than tinkering my vimrc.

Probably using both asdf-vm and Visual Studio for Mac caused some internal problems, which made dotnet to get stuck in a hanging status with gradually increasing memory leak.

After uninstalling VS for Mac and VS code, the high memory problem stopped occurring again.